# curved lines in a journey(timeline)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a journey(timeline) which look like below image.
[image]

It is having 15 stages total and i am displaying it without scrolling the page.

I am able to make this in a straight lines but  I am not able to make them curved across the whole line.

How can I achieve it?

below is my code of html and css

```css
.timeline{
      margin-top: 100px;
      /* width: 390px; */
    }
    .row{
           display: flex;
           margin: 0px 0;
           background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/kCcH1d/dot.png');
           background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
           width: 390px;
         }


         .circle{
           height: 30px;
           width: 30px;
           background: red;
           border-radius: 50%;
           text-align: center;
           margin-right: 50px;
           margin-left: 50px;
           margin-top: -15px;
           display: flex;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
         }

         .row.right:after {
          height: 70px;
          background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/eibc1d/dot2.png');
          background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
          content: "";
          width: 2px;
      }
        .row.left:before {
         height: 70px;
         background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/eibc1d/dot2.png');
         background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
         content: "";
         width: 2px;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="timeline">
      <div class="row right">
        <div class="circle"> A </div>
        <div class="circle"> B </div>
        <div class="circle"> C </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row left">
        <div class="circle"> D </div>
        <div class="circle"> E </div>
        <div class="circle"> F </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row right">
        <div class="circle"> G </div>
        <div class="circle"> H </div>
        <div class="circle"> I </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row left">
        <div class="circle"> J </div>
        <div class="circle"> K </div>
        <div class="circle"> L </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row right">
        <div class="circle"> M </div>
        <div class="circle"> N </div>
        <div class="circle"> 0 </div>
      </div>

    </div>



   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to draw it with the canvas element?
Should this be a cross browser solution?

Comment: @MoritzJaeger, using canvas element? no. yes it will be visible in all the major browser

Comment: You should use svg for this

Comment: these stages are clickable. using svg, I may be able to draw shapes but then what about stages ?

Comment: Use a svg circle for stages. You can assign an onclick event to them

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rudimentary example of how to do this using SVG (I just draw this using Adobe Experience Design), the parent group inside the circles contains an onclick event sending the index position order to a JS function, hope this helps

```js
function eventthis(position,obj){
  console.log('clicked in position ',position);
  //do stuff 
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 500">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        clip-path: url(#clip-Custom_Size_1);
      }

      .cls-2, .cls-5 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-2, .cls-3 {
        stroke: #707070;
      }

      .cls-3, .cls-6 {
        fill: #fff;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        stroke: none;
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="clip-Custom_Size_1">
      <rect width="300" height="500"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="Custom_Size_1" data-name="Custom Size – 1" class="cls-1">
    <rect class="cls-6" width="300" height="500"/>
    <path id="Path_1" stroke-dasharray="3" data-name="Path 1" class="cls-2" d="M24.621,20.759s227.3-30.868,227.44,35S57.809,52.051,52.528,108.6s181.931,3.044,188.138,66.8c-2.136,14.672,16.033,76.56-78.386,56.463S42.461,229.014,47.672,265.7s213.89-23.538,204.39,63.023c-5.839,15.735,10.235,57.524-139.437,35.4-71.377-4.844-77.94,71.9-77.94,71.9" transform="translate(11 17)"/>
    <g id="Ellipse_1" data-name="Ellipse 1" class="cls-3" transform="translate(20 25)" onclick="eventthis(1,this)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Ellipse_2" onclick="eventthis(2,this)" data-name="Ellipse 2" class="cls-3" transform="translate(248 51)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Ellipse_3" onclick="eventthis(3)" data-name="Ellipse 3" class="cls-3" transform="translate(46 103)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Ellipse_4" onclick="eventthis(4,this)" data-name="Ellipse 4" class="cls-3" transform="translate(232 162)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Ellipse_5" onclick="eventthis(5,this)" data-name="Ellipse 5" class="cls-3" transform="translate(46 235)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Ellipse_6" onclick="eventthis(6,this)" data-name="Ellipse 6" class="cls-3" transform="translate(232 300)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Ellipse_7" onclick="eventthis(7,this)" data-name="Ellipse 7" class="cls-3" transform="translate(51 384)">
      <circle class="cls-4" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15.5"/>
      <circle class="cls-5" cx="15.5" cy="15.5" r="15"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```